# Name that ie6/7 bug?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have an issue with a layout which only occurs with ie6 or 7 (or ie8 in compatibility view). The layout in question is here:

https://dustinhendricks.com/breastfest/public_html/

It's a site for a non-profit supporting breast cancer so it *is* suitable for work.

The problem I am having is with the small ribbon image next to the Make a Donation button. It seems to have a double margin-top. The element is not floated, which is the typical cause of a bug like this. I have tried applying `display: inline`, but that has no effect. Any ideas as to which ie 6/7 bug may be causing this, and how to fix?

The css for the element is:

```
#main #upper #info .ribbon {
    margin-left: 1px;
    margin-top: 33px;
}
```

And the parent element:

```
#main #upper #info {
    width: 279px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 25px;
    top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Side note: Your page has no `<title>`

Comment: Try putting the ribbon inside the form along with the "make a donation" button?

Comment: Can you narrow this down to a reproducible test case, aka demo? Debugging an entire page, especially one that's prone to your live edits, is going to make the problem that much harder to identify.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing as Shredder, give them a common top. But I think that IE pre8 just calculated the top different, and that's the base problem. I would do what Shredder said, but that's just me.

Comment: Floats only cause double horizontal margins on IE6. I don't know of any bugs that double the vertical margins.

Comment: @BoltClock yes, but it was the only thing I could think to try a fix for.

Comment: @Madmartigan http://jsfiddle.net/wEdvf/ notice the different top used on the green box when in ie7

Comment: I don't see the bug in your jsfiddle :/

Comment: @Shredder in most browsers, the top of the green box will be the bottom of the yellow box, but in ie6/7, the top of the green box will be the top of the lower red box instead. this is essentially the bug I am dealing with. fortunately I solved it by putting the form and image in a `clear: all` div, which unified the appearance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the bug was that the img element used the top of the adjacent floating element as its top instead of the bottom of the img element above like it does in all other browsers.

Fixed by wrapping both the adjacent floating element and the img element in a `clear: all` div, which forced the same top to be used across all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

In my experimenting with IE7 (I no longer have an easy way to test IE6), simply getting rid of the `margin-top: 33px` looked good (or at least reduce it to just about `4px`). This could be done by targeting those browsers.

However, perhaps a more cross browser solution that seemed to work is to reduce the margin on that for all browsers, and add a `margin-bottom` (about `29px`?) to the `#main #upper #info .ticket`. That seemed to work for both Firefox and IE7.

I think the root of the issue is that your floated class `.button-large` next to it for modern browsers allows the ribbon to interact with the ticket above, but for IE7, it seems to not try to raise the ribbon up under the ticket, but already aligns it to the top of the floated element at the left, so the extra margin pushes it down from that point.